# C take input about transitive relations

Tags: c, input, scanf, c99

How do I accept input like this:

```
a<b
b<c
```

and also like this:

```
a<b,c
d<e
f<x,y,z
```

Currently I'm able to read single statements like a < b, but not multiple statements in a line like a < b,c.

My code for single statements was:

```
char a, b;
while(scanf("%c<%c\n", &a, &b) == 2)
    /* Set alpha[0..26][0..26] to 1 */
    alpha[a - 'a'][b - 'a'] = 1;
```

I tried something like this for multiple statements per line:

```
char a;
while(scanf("%c<", &a)) {
    char b;
    while(scanf("%c,", &b)) {
        if(getchar() == '\n') break;
        /* Set alpha[0..26][0..26] to 1 */
        alpha[a - 'a'][b - 'a'] = 1;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't do what I want. It gets stuck in the first while loop.
I'm not very good with scanf and reading input in C. So some help would be appreciated.

Comment: i think your first loop lacking break condition like second one has `if(getchar() == '\n') break`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `getchar` to solve it.

The follow `code` could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int a;
    int b;
    char alpha[100][100];

    while ((a=getchar()) != EOF) {
        getchar(); // for <
        while((b=getchar()) != '\n') {
            /* Set alpha[0..26][0..26] to 1 */
            alpha[a - 'a'][b - 'a'] = 1;
            b = getchar();
            if (b == ',')
                continue;
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read each expression to a string, then parse it using `sscanf()` and the `%n` pattern to obtain the length of the parsed part. (Just note that `%n` is not counted as a conversion by most C libraries.)

For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define  STRINGIFY_(x) #x
#define  STRINGIFY(x)  STRINGIFY_(x)

#ifndef  MAX_WORD_LEN
#define  MAX_WORD_LEN  31
#endif
#define  SCAN_WORD "%" STRINGIFY(MAX_WORD_LEN) "[^\t\n\v\f\r <,;]"

const char *parse(const char *spec,
                  void      (*callback)(const char *less, const char *greater))
{
    char  less[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];
    char  more[MAX_WORD_LEN+1];
    int   len;

    while (1) {

        /* Skip an optional semicolon. */
        len = -1;
        if (sscanf(spec, " ; %n", &len) >= 0 && len > 0)
            spec += len;

        /* Try parsing the first pair. */
        len = -1;
        if (sscanf(spec, " " SCAN_WORD " < " SCAN_WORD " %n", less, more, &len) < 2 || len < 0)
            break;

        /* Report it. */
        if (callback)
            callback(less, more);

        /* Scan additional right sides. */
        spec += len;
        while (1) {

            len = -1;
            if (sscanf(spec, " , " SCAN_WORD " %n", more, &len) < 1 || len < 0)
                break; /* Only out of this inner while loop. */

            /* Report this one too. */
            if (callback)
                callback(less, more);

            spec += len;
        }
    }

    /* Return a pointer to the first unparsed character. */
    return spec;
}
```

An example program to apply it to each expression specified on the command line:

```
void report(const char *left, const char *right)
{
    printf("    %s < %s\n", left, right);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int         arg;
    const char *end;

    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {
        printf("%s:\n", argv[arg]);

        end = parse(argv[arg], report);
        if (*end)
            printf("but with '%s' not parsed.\n", end);
        else
            printf("completely parsed.\n");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If you compile the above to say `example`, and you run

```
./example 'foo < bar foo < baz, war war < bar'
```

the program will output

```
foo < bar foo < baz, war war < bar:
    foo < bar
    foo < baz
    foo < war
    war < bar
completely parsed.
```

That is, the callback function (`report()`, above) will be called once per unique pair. It accepts "words" as names, not just single letters. Each "word" can be up to 31 character long, and can contain any characters except whitespace, `<`, `,`, or `;`.

For completeness, it allows semicolons between subexpressions, and ignores them.

The logic itself is simple.

First, `parse()` tries to scan a semicolon. Any whitespace around it will be skipped as well.

Next, it tries to scan a pair of "words" with a `<` in between. If this fails, it breaks out of the infinite loop, and returns a pointer to the first unparsed character. It will point to a NUL byte (`\0`) if the syntax of the expression was correct.

If a pair was scanned, the callback function is called for the pair (unless the callback function is NULL).

Next, an inner loop tries to scan a comma followed by a "word". As long as this succeeds, the callback function will be called for the pair (using the original left side, and this new "word" as the right side). Otherwise, we break out of the inner loop, and start a new iteration of the outer loop.

So, if we look at say `foo < bar foo < baz, war war < bar`, then `foo < bar` will be parsed by the first iteration of the outer loop; `foo < baz` will be parsed by the second iteration of the outer loop, and `, war` by the inner loop; and finally `war < bar` will be parsed by the third iteration of the outermost loop.